# An adjective describing "someone who is doing his best given the circumstances"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm writing a research paper on the effect of a predictable income change on household consumption, labor supply, etc.

At its core, I ask if households are improvident or simply "doing their best given the circumstances". I.e. if households in fact do anticipate the change but are unable to do anything about it.

Hence, here lies my question. What do I call someone/a household which is simply doing its best given the unfavorable situation they are in?

Extra: If it sounds nice in combination with improvident, I can also use it for the title of the paper. For instance, "Improvident or [Incapable]: The Consumption Response to Predictable Changes in Income".

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you intend to imply by *improvident* in the first place? Have you looked up the word in a good dictionary? I strongly feel that's not the word you mean in the context at all. Please review and revise. Good Luck.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the `antonym` for **Improvident**, which is **Provident**.

**Improvident**: `adj` *Careless, Spenthrift*

**Provident**: `adj` *Careful, Frugal*

Thus, your title could be, '**Improvident or Provident?**'.

If that doesn't sit well enough with 'Someone doing the best under the circumstances', then perhaps you could use 'resultantly', although this would probably not fit with the title.

**Resultantly**: `adv` *in an appropriate, suitable way*

Comment: Does the OP really mean *improvident* in the first place?